# R: enumerating possible sequences to break ties in a ranking

Tags: r, algorithm, function, ranking

```
  MEMORY1 MEMORY2 MEMORY3 MEMORY4 MEMORY5 MEMORY6 MEMORY7 MEMORY8
        1     2.5     2.5       4       5       6       7       8
```

Suppose I have the above ranking of 8 items. There are 2 ways to break this tie: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` or `1 3 2 4 5 6 7 8`. I am trying to write a function which outputs these two possible sequences when given the original ranking with ties in it.

In the case of

```
  MEMORY1 MEMORY2 MEMORY3 MEMORY4 MEMORY5 MEMORY6 MEMORY7 MEMORY8
      4.5     4.5     4.5     4.5     4.5     4.5     4.5     4.5
```

All items are tied, so there's `8!` possible sequences. `permn(8)` or something similar would enumerate the sequences just fine.

In the case of

```
  MEMORY1 MEMORY2 MEMORY3 MEMORY4 MEMORY5 MEMORY6 MEMORY7 MEMORY8
      7.5       5       5       2     7.5       2       2       5
```

There are `3! x 3! x 2! = 72` possible sequences. How can I write a function that outputs these 72 possible sequences given the original ranking?

```
myfun = function(ranking){
  output = vector()
  values = sort(unique(ranking))
  if(length(values) < 8){
    #if there are ties
    for(i in 1:length(values)){
      value_in_question = values[i]
      if(sum(value_in_question %in% values[i] == 1)){
        output = output
      }else output[i] = permn(values[i])
    }
  }
  return(output)
}
```

This is my attempt, it doesn't work. And I'm having trouble coming up with a way to enumerate the sequences when there are multiple ties...

**EDIT:**

```
dat = c(2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5)
names(dat) <- paste0("MEMORY", 1:8)

## Group similar items, compute run lengths, then permute
library(combinat) # permn
gs <- cumsum(abs(c(0, diff(sort(dat)))) > 1e-9)
lens <- rle(gs)$lengths
lst <- mapply(function(a,b) lapply(permn(1:b), `+`, a), c(0, cumsum(head(lens, -1))), lens)

## Expand into data.frame (don't expand if all were the same)
res <- if(!is.null(dim(lst)) && dim(lst)[2] == 1) lst else expand.grid(lst)

 Error: cannot allocate vector of size 16.0 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)) :
  Reached total allocation of 8070Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)) :
  Reached total allocation of 8070Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)) :
  Reached total allocation of 8070Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)) :
  Reached total allocation of 8070Mb: see help(memory.size)
5: In rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)) :
  Reached total allocation of 8070Mb: see help(memory.size)
6: In rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)) :
  Reached total allocation of 8070Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

Comment: did you mean to tag this R? you haven't provided any R code...

Comment: @TanDollars I have added the function I have been writing, but it doesn't work very well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are comparing floats, you don't want to use `==` tests.  Instead, check that the difference between numbers is sufficiently small.  Here is a possible solution that makes no claims on efficiency.

```
## Example
dat <- c(7.5, 5, 5, 2, 7.5, 2, 2, 5)
names(dat) <- paste0("MEMORY", 1:8)

## Group similar items, compute run lengths, then permute
library(combinat) # permn
gs <- cumsum(abs(c(0, diff(sort(dat)))) > 1e-9)
lens <- rle(gs)$lengths
lst <- mapply(function(a,b) lapply(permn(1:b), `+`, a),
              c(0, cumsum(head(lens, -1))), lens, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

## Expand into data.frame (don't expand if all were the same)
res <- if(!is.null(dim(lst)) && dim(lst)[2] == 1) lst else expand.grid(lst)

## Unnest columns if desired
res <- data.frame(t(apply(res, 1, unlist)))

## Name the columns
names(res) <- names(sort(dat))

head(res)
#   MEMORY4 MEMORY6 MEMORY7 MEMORY2 MEMORY3 MEMORY8 MEMORY1 MEMORY5
# 1       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8
# 2       1       3       2       4       5       6       7       8
# 3       3       1       2       4       5       6       7       8
# 4       3       2       1       4       5       6       7       8
# 5       2       3       1       4       5       6       7       8
# 6       2       1       3       4       5       6       7       8
## Gets all 72 sequences from example: 3!*3!*2!
nrow(res)
# [1] 72
```

The result should be a data.frame where each row is one of the possible sequences (the sequences being indexes of the sorted data).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I forgot to specify something about the problem. Given the ranking `7.5 5 5 2 7.5 2 2 5`, each rank corresponds to a MEMORY item (i.e 7.5 is MEMORY1's rank, 5 is MEMORY2's rank, etc). So in that case MEMORY1 can either be 7 or 8. Same goes for MEMORY5. `7 x x x 8 x x x` or `8 x x x 7 x x x`. Is there a way to take this into consideration?

Comment: @Adrian if I understand you correctly, this is already taken into account.  The resulting rows in the data.frame correspond to indices of the sorted data.  I will rename the columns to make this clearer.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: I am running into memory allocation problems because some of the permutations are too big. I have edited my original post, could you take a look at that?

Comment: @Adrian ok, it looks like `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` should be added to the `mapply`, see update

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks.